# THttpServer and Flash application

Tags: flash, delphi, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have an http server created with Delphi, which is supposed to provide some data to a Flash web application.
The server works fine, it's bound to a port 7777, and i can make sucessfuly queries with browsers, anyway when I am trying to query it from the flash application - i am receiving the follow errors :

```
Error: [strict] Ignoring policy file at http://192.168.0.194:7777/crossdomain.xml due to incorrect syntax.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix this problem.

Warning: Domain 192.168.0.194 does not specify a meta-policy.  Applying default meta-policy 'master-only'.  This configuration is deprecated.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix this problem.

Error: Ignoring policy file at http://192.168.0.194:7777/?crossdomain.xml due to meta-policy 'master-only'
```

.

```
<cross-domain-policy>


<allow-access-from domain="192.168.0.222"/>

</cross-domain-policy>
```

this is my crossdomain, which i am requesting on port 7777 again.

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.allowDomain("http://192.168.0.194");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("http://192.168.0.194");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://192.168.0.194:7777/?crossdomain.xml");
```

this is the code on onCreateApplication in Flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your crossdomain.xml :

```
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
```

Read [fplayer_security](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0) article first, for all meta-policies available,

Try to use something else than the default "master-only" value.

Comment: nope, unfortunately it's the same issue with this one too:

Comment: @YordanYanakiev : have you tried another `policy` than `master-only` ?